# rounded corners cropping

Tags: html, css, rounded-corners

I am having issues with rounding corners, they keep wanting to crop off on the left side by a few pixels.  Below is the code I am using.  I've tried increasing numbers and decreasing numbers; I've added a wrapper; I've tried all different solutions I can find for searching, but it still crops off. Can anyone give me a hand since I don't seem to be very handy?  And apparently I can't post a picture of what it looks like either.

```
<style>
.image 
{
    width: 200px;
    position:relative;
    -webkit-border-radius: 14px;
    -moz-border-radius: 14px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 14px;  
    border-radius: 14px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#slideshow 
{
    margin:0 0 0 0;
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    height:133px;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-border-radius: 14px;
    -moz-border-radius: 14px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 14px; 
    border-radius: 14px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

#slideshow > div 
{
    position:absolute;
}
</style>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
    $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
    setInterval(function() 
    {
        $('#slideshow > div:first')
            .fadeOut(2000)
            .next()
            .fadeIn(2000)
            .end()
            .appendTo('#slideshow');
    }, 3000);
});
</script>


<div id="slideshow">
    <div class="image"><img alt="" class="icon-action" src="img url" width="200"/></div>
    <div class="image"><img alt="" class="icon-action" src="img url" width="200"/></div>
    <div class="image"><img alt="" class="icon-action" src="img url" width="200"/></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Start adding a jsFiddle for those kind of issues.

Comment: Weird, here works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Y7nEy/

Comment: There is no cropping here : http://jsfiddle.net/6xxu5/ what is your browser ?

Comment: Could you tell us exactly HOW it's cropped? And are you sure it's not caused by an overlapping image or div or something?

Answer (score 1):

I had the very same problem when the `border-radius` spec came out. Turns out you have to add `border-radius` to the `<img>` tag. Then you can either keep or remove the `<div>`'s `border-radius` property.

Comment: Thanks; I'll keep plugging away.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you need to be dealing with nested rounded corners which are fairly helpfully generator with this useful tool.

http://joshnh.com/tools/get-your-nested-border-radii-right.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
div.circle 
{ 
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 28px;
    -moz-border-radius: 64px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 64px; padding:32px; 
     border: 2px black;
     color:white;
     text-align:center;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgb(255,0,0);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgb(255,0,0); box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgb(255,0,0); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to solve this issue using the following css. This has worked on my sites I hope it can help you out with your problem. Not sure if it's a argument you are missing or not.

```
.classname {
-moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ededed), color-stop(1, #dfdfdf) );
background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ededed 5%, #dfdfdf 100% );
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ededed', endColorstr='#dfdfdf');
background-color:#ededed;
-moz-border-radius:6px;
-webkit-border-radius:6px;
border-radius:6px;
border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
display:inline-block;
color:#777777;
font-family:arial;
font-size:15px;
font-weight:bold;
padding:6px 24px;
text-decoration:none;
text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #ffffff;
```

}